# Can Coffee Beans Be Re-Roasted?

Tags: beans, home-roasting

We mistakenly bought a pound of coffee beans that are either a light or medium roast. We only like dark roast and can't use these as is. Can we roast these on our stove until the beans look the color we like? We've never roasted our own beans so are totally inexperienced.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but a consideration. The roast and the beans aren't independent. Coffee roasters sample the beans to figure out what roast level will best bring out the flavor of those beans. If they were roasted light or medium, it's because that will bring out the best flavor from those beans. If you roast them darker, you will destroy much of the flavors that those beans offer. (cont'd)

Comment: I suspect re-roasting would not yield good results, anyway, because you would probably lose a lot of aroma components, and the beans will already have lost most of the internal moisture that produces the cracking (color, alone, can be hard to judge). But even if you could, you might not want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed this wouldn't work in the way you'd hope. I did a little research and it appears that the consensus on this is that "reroasting" beans don't really work because you end up essentially cooking the beans instead. You would end up with a burnt taste vs a more robust taste. [Coffee Wiki](https://www.coffeekiwi.com/beginners-guides/can-you-roast-coffee-beans-twice/) goes in-depth into the pitfalls of reroasting.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up not re-roasting after reading your research. To use it up, I mixed it at a 1:4 ratio with a French roast. Better than risking ruining it by re-roasting!